# Dynamic fill with transition d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to do dynamic fill with transition using d3.

http://tributary.io/inlet/11094354

how to do a transition on this to load 0-60% on first load??

Thanks and Best Regards
Moyeen

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a transition to the `stop`:

```
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").style("stop-color", "red")
    .transition().duration(1000).attr("offset", "60%");
```

Complete demo [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/11111188).